# Running multiple nUnit tests triggers "No connection" error, but running individually works (JetBrains Rider)

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, jetbrains-ide, rider

I have a very simple Selenium c# structure as follows:

```html
using System;
using System.Timers;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    internal class Program
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
        }

        [SetUp]
        public void Initialize()
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.pt/");
            Console.WriteLine("INITIALIZE complete");
        }
        
        [Test]
        public void TestGoogleSearch()
        {
            IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
            
            element.SendKeys("ivo cunha");
            Console.WriteLine("IVO complete");
        }
        
        [Test]
        public void TestGoogleSearch2()
        {
            IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
            
            element.SendKeys("adam o'brien");
            Console.WriteLine("ADAM complete");
        }
        
        [TearDown]
        public void CleanUp()
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2500);
            driver.Close();
            driver.Quit();
            driver.Dispose();
            Console.WriteLine("CLEANUP complete");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run each test unit, each passes. But if I run all test units (just 2 in this case), it fails with the following error:

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Unexpected error. System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:57535

[image: Screenshot of the results when running all tests]

How can I fix this so that I can run all tests at in a series?

Comment: Seems like you are trying to connect to the following address 127.0.0.1:57535 but it's not available

Comment: But how come it works for the first test? And then fails for the second test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your instancing a ChromeDriver, it creates a socket that is being used for the tests.

Then you are using `TearDown` that runs after each test, so it basically closes the connection after the `TearDown` and doesn't open it again for the second test.

So you either:

- Close `ChromeDriver` only after all tests are done.
- Close `ChromeDriver` and create new instance after each test.

Here's an example with the second solution

```
using System;
using System.Timers;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    internal class Program
    {
        IWebDriver driver = null;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }

        [SetUp]
        public void Initialize()
        {
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.pt/");
            Console.WriteLine("INITIALIZE complete");
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestGoogleSearch()
        {
            IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));

            element.SendKeys("ivo cunha");
            Console.WriteLine("IVO complete");
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestGoogleSearch2()
        {
            IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));

            element.SendKeys("adam o'brien");
            Console.WriteLine("ADAM complete");
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void CleanUp()
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2500);
            driver.Close();
            driver.Quit();
            driver.Dispose();
            Console.WriteLine("CLEANUP complete");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shlomi, your explanation makes perfect sense :) it works.